# How to get data with \n in react using fetch or any method?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
{"story_id":5,
"title":"Hello gracious",
"community_name":"Mental Health",
"short_story":"Hello gracious",
"img_url":"/Y4l4FQYsmny7RvTMW3r5kLnPZyaeJsuN1QgzRq87FBFSv4GvYb2021-01-01Asset 5.png",
"body":"What is Lorem Ipsum?\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy\ntext of the printing"}

 fetch('http://localhost:5000/getParticularStory)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })

    }, [])
```

After I fetched with API form node I am getting only

body: "What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing"

I want to fetch body with \n which I fetched from MySQL database.
Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Do you also control the API that is giving you the data back?

Comment: Yes. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Try returning the all data inside the body property. `{ body: { "story_id": 5, ... } }`

Comment: I get  `{"story_id":5,
"title":"Hello gracious",
"community_name":"Mental Health",
"short_story":"Hello gracious",
"img_url":"/Y4l4FQYsmny7RvTMW3r5kLnPZyaeJsuN1QgzRq87FBFSv4GvYb2021-01-01Asset 5.png",
"body":"What is Lorem Ipsum?\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy\ntext of the printing"}`

Comment: but after fecthing and convert it in to json \n is missing.

Comment: "convert it in to json" why are you converting it into JSON? - please share a [mcve]

Comment: After fetch  `.then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)` I got above result (without \n).